# How can I find and list the questions that I've previously asked on superuser?

Tags: support, user-profiles

I've at least found the users link where I can enter my member name and see some summary statistics about my account, but I have not yet found a way to find and list all of the questions that I've previously asked with links to go back to them and review their details again.

Comment: [Questions](https://superuser.com/users/652024?tab=questions), [answers](https://superuser.com/users/652024?tab=answers).

Answer (score 5):

Go to your account, select the "Activity" tab (should be selected by default when you open your account), and on the left you'll see the most recent answers and questions. The titles [Questions](https://meta.superuser.com/users/652024/fireblood?tab=questions) and [Answers](https://meta.superuser.com/users/652024/fireblood?tab=answers) are clickable and will take you to pages with all your questions and answers.